# PEAR Date date_create_from_format

Tags: php, date

Which PHP function do I use  to parse a date that is in the format "Fri, 28 Jan 2011 17:57:37 GMT"

strtotime doesn't seem to work for me on that date.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$date = date_create_from_format('D, j M Y H:i:s O', 'Fri, 28 Jan 2011 17:57:37 GMT')
```

Full docs on the format characters [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Beats me why couldn't look this up yourself - you've got the function name in your post's title.